# how do I get access to the object that I'm intercepting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle Core to create a custom attribute and interceptor to inject security checks into our code using attributes.
e.g. [Security("Role1")]

In the implementation of the interceptor:

```
public class SecurityInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        object o;

        MethodInfo mi = invocation.Method;
        SecurityAttribute[] atts = (SecurityAttribute[])mi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SecurityAttribute), true);

        // if method not marked with Security attribute, then pass on call
        if (atts.Length == 0)
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        else
        {
            //for now assume that there is only one security attribute on the method
            //do some security test 
            {
                invocation.Proceed();
            }
        }

    }
```

In the "do some security test" section above, I need access to the HttpContext.Session object in order to retrieve some saved objects to do the security test.

Assume the method that this attribute is on, is a code-behind asp.net page, i.e an instance of the Page class) 
I can't just use this.Context in the attribute like this [Security("Role1", this.Context)]
as attributes don't allow that.

So how do I get access to the httpContext inside the Intercept method?

Or is there a better way of doing this in an aspect-like way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `InvocationTarget` property of the `IInvocation` instance has the target object. So in your case, if you are certain that the interception happens on a `Page` object, you should be able to do this:

```
var page = (Page)invocation.InvocationTarget;
```

If that is not always the case, you should gain access to the HTTP context in another way.

It's true, as Ben points out, that `HttpContext.Current` gives you access to the current `HttpContext` from anywhere, but accessing that static property is just icky. There's a better way, however, and that is by registering a factory method that allows for injection of the session state:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<ISessionState>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(k => new SessionWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session)
        .Lifestyle.PerWebRequest));
```

assuming that you have created the `ISessionState` interface and an appropriate wrapper that has the API you wish to use when interacting with the ASP.NET `HttpSessionState` object.

Now, since the interceptor is pulled from the container like everything else, it can depend on `ISessionState`:

```
public class SecurityInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public SecurityInterceptor(ISessionState sessionState)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

which makes your interceptor nice and testable.

There's probably many other ways to do this, and possible better ways as well. This is just an idea on how you can get on with your project :)

Comment: A sidenote (perhaps it's worth re-editing the post) @mookid8000 - the FactorySupportFacility is not needed for `UsingFactoryMethod` (it was in older versions of Windsor). The facility is now useful only in legacy scenarios, like when you specify the factory via XML.

Comment: @Krzysztof I did not know that - thanks! I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Session` from anywhere so long as the code is being called from an ASP.net process.